# Postfix relay user if not found on local mail server

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have a particular need which seemed to be realizable with Postfix.

I have 2 mail servers at my disposal.

- the first in a local linux server which is managed by Postfix with Dovecot
- the second managed by gmail (pro) for some users (is not a @gmail.com mail)

For example I have user.a@domain.com on the local server, and user.b@domain.com manage by gmail.
If I send an email to user.a@domain.com, the local server takes over.
But if I send an email to user.b@domain.com, I would like this email to be redirected to gmail.

Currently the local part is working perfectly, however when I try to send a mail to user.b@domain.com (the user managed by gmail), the mail is rejected: "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table".

An idea ? Here is my configuration of main.cf (Postfix)

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_unknown_helo_hostname

disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport 

myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.ovh.net, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301 inet:localhost:54321
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301 inet:localhost:54321
```

Content of relay_recipients file :

```
user.b@domain.com
```

Content of transport file

```
user.b@domain.com relay:[smtp.google.com]:587
* local
```

Is it possible ?

---

My new configuration :

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/maws.fr/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/maws.fr/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_unknown_helo_hostname

disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

myhostname = vps42.ovh.net 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport  mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301 inet:localhost:54321
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301 inet:localhost:54321
```

Content of transport file :

```
user.b@domain.com relay:[smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

Now when I send a mail to user.a@domain.com (my local user) it managed in local.
If i send a mail to user.b@domain.com (managed by gmail) I receive my mail (victory !), but it is send in a loop (sad...) :

```
postfix/smtp[6097]: A601C44494: to=<user.b@domain.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[142.251.4.108]:587, delay=2.3, delays=0.38/0.03/1.3/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1622552412 j10sm9603207ilk.87 - gsmtp)
postfix/smtp[6097]: 2CC4844494: to=<user.b@domain.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.76.108]:587, delay=1.1, delays=0.42/0/0.3/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1622552415 o3sm3206340wrm.78 - gsmtp)
```

(small part of logs, it's send result, full log : https://mclo.gs/wOo6BFB)

I've sent a mail from user-test@orange.com to user.b@domain.com, and after a loop appear to send from user.b@domain.com to user.b@domain.com

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Where's your `relay_domains`? All you have in `$mydestination` is your local server name.

According to the [basic configuration README](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html):

> IMPORTANT: If your machine is a mail server for its entire domain, you must list $mydomain as well.

```
  Example 2: domain-wide mail server.

    /etc/postfix/main.cf:
        mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

If you aren't going to specify `$myhostname` as an FQDN (by default, Postfix will derive `$mydomain` by stripping off the first part), you're better off not specifying `$myhostname` and specify `$mydomain` instead, since Postfix will derive a hostname for you from that (more info in the basic configuration README).

Next, for your transport file, you need to ensure that if you're using `relay` in your transport map, you set up `$relayhost` with the Gmail destination and have a valid credential in `sasl_passwd` for it.

This guide has some useful information on setting up `$relayhost` and `sasl_passwd`: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-transport-map-relay-map-flexible-email-delivery

Also, I'm old-fashioned enough I'd want to explicitly specify my domain in `transport_maps` as well if I'm splitting my recipients:

```
user.b@domain.com smtp:[smtp.google.com]:587
domain.com        local
```